# change table engine from MyISAM to INNODB

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, innodb, myisam

I've inherited a project which has a mixture of table engines appx 50\50 in each of MyISAM & INNODB.

The front end code was all PHP but I'm using c#, MVC and the Entity Framework.

As such I'd like to add all the PK\FK relationships and therefore need to change the MyISAM tables to INNODB.

My question is, broadly speaking, how safe is it to make this change, is it likely or unlikely that there would be any impact on the front end code (select, updates, inserts, stored procs, views).

I know that in an ideal world I'd have units tests, a QA dept etc but as a solo developer I don't have such resources.

Comment: Broadly speaking, it will be somewhat safe to do it.

Comment: full text indexes, select count(*) without WHERE clause, geo indexes should alert you. However in 5.6 fulltext indexes are supported.